# Что обозначает тильда в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Что значит в данном случае тильда?

```
df = df.loc[~non_numberic_profits]
```

В столбец `non_numberic_profits` были заданы строки, которые не отвечают типу данных `float`. То есть, не цифры, а какие-то буквы или символы.

Что в данном случае значит тильда? Какую функцию она выполняет?

После данной сроки последовала следующая строка кода `

```
df.profit = df.profit.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Как я понимаю, она преобразовывает именно в тип данных `float`. Но что она преобразовывает? Оставшиеся значения? Не совсем понимаю, что выполняет оператор тильда в данном случае.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это операция `not`, которая часто применяется для инвертирования логических столбцов / значений.

[Из документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html):

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
> data. The operators are: `|` for or, `&` for and, and `~` for not.

Пример:

```
In [475]: s = pd.Series(np.random.choice([True, False], size=5))

In [476]: s
Out[476]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool

In [477]: ~s
Out[477]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

---

**UPD:** что делает команда `df = df.loc[~non_numberic_profits]`:

данная команда фильтрует фрейм таким образом что выбираются только те строки фрейма для которых в соответствующей позиции `non_numberic_profits` стоит значение `False`.

NOTE: длина `non_numberic_profits` должна совпадать с длиной (числом строк) `df`.

---

**UPD2:** что делает команда `df.profit = df.profit.apply(pd.to_numeric)`:

это не очень эффективный способ преобразовать все значения столбца к числовому типу данных `int64` или `float64`.

Лучше это делать так:

```
df["profit"] = pd.to_numeric(df["profit"], errors="coerce")
```

Comment: в данном случае тильда выступает оператором not и присваивает переменной df значение, что df будет равна df, но без переменной non_numberic_profits? я верно понял?

Comment: @АртёмКрашенинников, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: так, а что обозначает errors="coerce"?

Comment: If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN. Попробуйте: `pd.to_numeric(["1", "pi", "3.14"], errors="coerce")` - думаю станет понятнее)

Comment: теперь понял! Спасибо огромное ещё раз!!!

Comment: т.е. если мне надо сохранить все значения, но преобразовать столбец в другой тип данных, то лучше использовать сразу pd.to_numeric(df["profit"], errors="coerce"), где он неизвестные значения преобразует в числовое значение NaN? верно?

Comment: да, все правильно